# Where can I find a central repository of Android open source code?

Tags: android

When I was developing in PHP and Visual Basic, there were tons of programmers who provided their source code on various websites. Is there a central repository like [www.pscode.com](http://www.pscode.com) where I can find open source code released for Android?

Comment: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I would 100% recommend this :

http://commonsware.com/

It's a yearly subscription giving you access to three android books which are kept up-to-date as a PDF or Kindle copy. They are updated when changes are required such as a new SDK release.
You can also browse online sample code used in these books, here for [exemple](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android). These Samples are a gold mine to learn android, so start digging :D

Comment: wow.. haha thanks.. ahm commons guy are very expert in android. just wondering if their code is newbie friendly? Cause i saw some of their projects las time and its dificult for me to debug. some are just to complicated for me. BTW thanks for the link

Comment: @nelzkie some books are for professionel use and other for newbie

Comment: Thank you for the example link you gave me. I wish they are not to complicated for me. ^_^

Comment: @nelzkie start with this book http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials/ source code is here https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist

Answer (score 1):

There are many sites where willing coders release/share/discuss their codes.

You have for example the old [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) or the now very used [github](https://github.com/) (my preferred) or the [Google one](http://code.google.com/).

I've never heard of a specific one for android (which would be hard : all my open source projects have many parts in many technologies) but at least github and code.google let you search their projects by technology :

- https://github.com/languages
- http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aAndroid

Comment: i believe github is for professional only? ^_^.. do they have some basic android source code for beginners there?

Comment: No github isn't for professional only : github is mainly known for the free open source repositories, even if you can also rent private repositories. But you won't find a category "for beginner" as they offer code sharing, not tutorials.

Comment: A repository is the set of your files that defines your project. You usually manage/share them using a [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software) like git (hence "github). Try to learn git at github at the same time you learn programming, that's very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Android itself is available as open source [Android source code](http://source.android.com/index.html), otherwise, look at [code.google.com - Android label](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aAndroid) where there are tons of projects available, including sources

Comment: if im right http://source.android.com/index.html uses git? is there any other way to download a project in zip or folder only?

Comment: Apparently submitted an answer almost simultaneously with dystroy, buthe/she beat me to it, and already provides the main link to code.google.com :-)

Comment: Specific versions (google is your friend :-)); http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1 as example

Comment: T_T.. i dont understand.. why do they have to do it.... its just to much work for me to use git instead of downloading it directly..

Comment: Deleted the comment before, since I found a link to downloadable google source (in jar format), see link in previous comment

Comment: oh.. i downloaded it in jar format.. how to see its source code?

Comment: a jar is a zip. Rename to zip and unzip it